# Is this schematic correct?

Tags: arduino, power, mosfet, motor, schematics

I'm working on an Arduino project and before I set off to build it completely I wanted to see if my schematic works or if something would go wrong.

The goal of the project is to be a sort of ball launcher, where the LCD holds a counter of how many balls launched, the distance sensor detects if anything is in front of it, a servo to stop the ball.

To launch the ball I have a 12V 3A DC motor like this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08662QSZL) and i'm using a [IRF3205](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071R6RPVS) to control the speed of the motor through the `analogWrite()` function of the Arduino. I originally tried this with a smaller 5V motor and a TIP120 like in the picture.

[image]

And while it did work I read someone recommending the IRF3708 instead of the Darlington Transistor (I got the IRF3205 because I couldn't get the other one, I read it was very similar but I could be wrong).

[image]

This is my attempt at the schematic for this project but i'm not sure if something there is wrong or if I should add something else.

This are some of the components i'm using:

1. Arduino Nano
2. 12V 3A Power Supply connected to a DC-005 Jack
3. IRF3205 Mosfet
4. MR506 600V 3A Diode
5. 2.2k Resistor
6. 12V 3A DC Motor
7. Mp1584 Buck Converter
8. LCD
9. HC-SR04 Distance Sensor
10. MG90S Servo

I'm pretty new to this so any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Q1 is a problem.  The Gate should be connected to R1 (ground is on the correct pin, swap the other two), but the transistor itself is not a good choice for this circuit.  That transistor will not be fully on at Vgs=5V.  You need a logic level mosfet for the switch that is fully saturated at Vgs=5V.

Comment: I originally found [this](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/mosfet-comparison-for-arduino-logic-level-irlz44n-irf3205-fqp30n06l.168699/#:~:text=The%20IRLZ44N%20had%20the%20lowest,as%20a%20logic%20level%20MOSFET.&text=The%20IRF3205%20was%20deemed%20too,a%20current%20of%204.1%20A.) forum talking about how even though its not logic level but it still would work with an Arduino. For the other two options, sadly I have no way of getting them.

Comment: At 3A, Q1 will get very hot at Vgs=5V.  You can put a heat sink on Q1 but using a more appropriate mosfet is a better idea (there are 1000's to choose from)

Comment: I see, could you please recommend one for this project? I'm very new to electronics and transistors in general. Thanks!

Comment: A better idea if you have limited experience is to get one of the external hot bed mosfet boards for 3d printers (opto-isolated n channel mosfet rated for 10 or so amps like https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Power-Module-Expansion-Printer/dp/B07CGN7NCG)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments: Q1 needs to be redrawn. Hope this helps. Which FET, MOSFET, Etc. is something for someone with more knowledge than mine. I'm just showing you Q1. Hopefully I didn't mess it up. Lots of cut/paste in photoshop.[image]

Comment: Double check the DC power jack DC1. The way it is drawn shows negative on the post and positive on the shell. Most such power jacks have positive on the inner pin and negative (GND) on the shell.